# Rancher Pipeline nightly build

Tags: rancher

I was looking through the docs and wrote an [issue](https://github.com/rancher/docs/issues/2404) on GitHub. I can't find a way to schedule Pipeline execution on Rancher.

Does anyone have a solution already?

Comment: Sens, are you referring to the Rancher Pipeline feature in 2.x or something else?  Could you reference the issue for more information?

Comment: Ah thanks, i added a link on issue. And I'm talking about Rancher 2.x Pipeline yes.